# Upgrade Solrcloud 4.10.2 to 5.2.1

Tags: solr, architecture, solr4, solrcloud, solr5

I have SolrCloud 4.10.2 version setup with 4 nodes running successfully in the production.Now I want to upgrade this setup to 5.2.1 version.I want to make sure that my application accessing solr is not experiencing any downtime during upgrade.

As of now I am thinking to nodes one by one.That means I will stop one node,upgrade it by replacing solr.war & start it.Now my worry is will there be any problem till I upgrade other 3 nodes to 5.2.1 as there will be version mismatch between Solr nodes?

How solr upgrade is handled in the industry?

Comment: Starting in Solr5 running a WAR file [is not supported](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4792). It might work, but they don't support it anymore. The only supported option is to use the service which runs on Jetty.

Comment: Our upgrade path from Solr4 to Solr5 was setup solr 5 from scratch and reindex *everything*. There were some changes that needed to happen in our schema, too. Our solr4 schema did not work on solr5.

Answer (score 0):

Solr 5 supports upgrades from 4.x. Here is the link to the apache wiki describing the steps:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Upgrading+a+Solr+Cluster

I have done this on live data, upgrading from 4.10.2 to 5.2.1. I upgraded one node at the time. Works well. The caveat is to check your schema and make sure you are not using the deprecated types that have been removed in solr 5.x. Also check the "planning your upgrade" for additional steps you may need to take before upgrading.